# What Excel formula can create a string containing sequential numbers? AKA REPT() with a counter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have column A with a number in it.  I want to put a formula in column B that gives me that number of repetitions of a string, concatenated together, with the number of the repetition embedded in it.

Example desired result:

```
 A     B
---   -------------
 1     , the #1 string
 0     
       , the string
 4     , the #1 string, the #2 string, the #3 string, the #4 string
```

(I'm on Excel 2013, if it matters.)

Comment: How large a number of repetitions can there be (formula vs. VBA requirement)?

Comment: @fixer1234 If you're asking for performance considerations, those can be neglected.  But for my current purposes, let's say 300.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't have a lot of functionality for concatenating strings in this way. The REPT() function doesn't work with arrays which means it cant loop through different values.

My suggestion would be to set yourself up like this:

[image]

For the following results:

[image]

Note that this example only works if you put an apostrophe in cells **C1** and **A5**.

I look forward to seeing if there is a better solution.